# How to list categories by shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

Could not find answer on this question, even this could be easy.
I want to display inline categories of current post by shortcode and divided by comma.
I tried it like this below.

```
function genre( $atts, $content = null ) {
$categories = the_category(', ');
    return '<div id="genre"><b>Genre: </b>' . $categories . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("genre", "genre");
```

This returns `Genre:`

```
function genre( $atts, $content = null ) {
$categories = get_the_category(', ');
    return '<div id="genre"><b>Genre: </b>' . $categories . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("genre", "genre");
```

This returns `Genre: Array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function genre( $atts, $content = null ) {
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category_list( ', ', '', $post->ID );
 return '<div id="genre"><b>Genre: </b>' . $categories . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode("genre", "genre");
```

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-list-categories-by-shortcode

Answer (score 1):

without using a plugin you would need to generate a function yourself. alternatively you can add the following to your template:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

the documentation can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [wp_list_categories():](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

```
function genre() {
    $list = wp_list_categories( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'echo'       => '',
        'title_li'   => '',
        // other args here
    ) );

     return "<ul>$list</ul>";

}

add_shortcode("genre", "genre");
```